# Check that $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}$ is bounded from above by $\frac 34$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Any ideas on how to check that

$
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k} \le \frac 34\,?
$

It's pretty easy to see that the sequence is monotonic and has an almost trivial upper bound of $1$ (and a trivial lower bound of $1/2$).

I solved it several years ago but can't recall my solution. I do remember I scratched my head for a while, though. I'm quite sure one needs to get an upper bound through some algebraic manipulation to get $\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac {1}{k^2}$ (well, some polynomial of order 2 in $k$) but can't recover the proper way to do it (without relying on integral calculus).

Wolframalpha suggests that $\lim_n a_n = \ln(2)$, which can be easily seen by integration. Is there a `more' elementary way to see it? My guess would be no.

Comment: My bad, I meant 3/4. Editing original post.

Comment: Isn't it enough to compute the limit? The sequence is convergent and increasing, so the limit is the supremum of its image. Since it is $\log 2$ then it is trivially less than 3/4. I'm not sure about what kind of solution you're looking for.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not sure that ``seeing'' that the limit is $\log 2$ can be done without some integral calculus.

Comment: Isn't the integral test for the graph of $\frac{1}{x}$ simply enough to see this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n+1+k}\\&\quad\text{and}\\
S&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{2n-k}\end{align}$$

So $$\begin{align}2S&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{n+1+k}+\frac{1}{2n-k}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{3n+1}{(n+1+k)(2n-k)}
\end{align}$$

The shape of $(n+1+k)(2n-k)$ is increasing for $k<\frac{n-1}{2}$ and decreasing for $k>\frac{n-1}{2}$. So the minimum value here for $k=0,\dots,n-1$ is either when $k=0$ or $k=n-1$, which are the same value, $(n+1)2n$.

So:

$$\frac{3n+1}{(n+1+k)(2n-k)}\leq \frac{3n+1}{2n(n+1)}$$ and summing we get:

$$2S\leq \frac{n(3n+1)}{2n(n+1)}=\frac{3n+1}{2n+2}<\frac{3n+3}{2n+2}=\frac{3}{2}$$

We also get $(n+1-k)(2n-k)\leq \left(\frac{3n+1}{2}\right)^2$. So:

$$2S\geq \frac{4n(3n+1)}{(3n+1)^2}=\frac{4n}{3n+1}$$ or $$S\geq \frac{2n}{3n+1}$$

That's not really much of a lower bound, since $a_9>\frac{2}{3}.$

Comment: Not the way I was thinking of, but I do like this one quite a bit. It even gives a better lower bound. If I ever recall what I did, I will keep you guys posted!

Answer (score 3):

Replace $n$ by $5n$ and split the sum into $5$ parts
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{5n} \frac{1}{5n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{5n+k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{6n+k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{7n+k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{8n+k} +\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{9n+k} \\ \leq \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{9}   = \frac{1879}{2520} < \frac{3}{4}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Very cute answer. Since the $a_n$ can be seen as increasing, you only need to know it is true for $n$ a multiple of $5$.

Comment: More generally, replace $5$ with $m$, you get that $a_{mn}\leq \frac{1}{2m}+a_m.$ This gives you better and better upper bounds.

Answer (score 2):

By C-S $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n+k}-\frac{1}{n}\right)+1=1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{n(n+k)}=$$
$$=1-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{n^2k+nk^2}\leq1-\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\right)^2}{n^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk+n\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^2}=1-\frac{\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}}{\frac{n^3(n+1)}{2}+\frac{n^2(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}}\leq\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: You've been around long enough to know how to use `\begin{align}...\end{align}`. And the main step here is opaque. Use your words.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think Michael prefers to not use the align commands, and although *opaque* as you put it, it still answers the question, and quite finely in my opinion. Perhaps he could elaborate on what *By C-S* actually means, so in that case, **C-S = Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality**.

Comment: @user477343 Whatever he prefers, it formats terribly on various browsers. On my iPad, it lost the $\leq \frac{3}{4}.$ It looks horrible even without that - it is hard to tell where the expressions begin and end without careful eye-balling.

Answer (score 2):

If you already proved that $H_{2n}-H_n$ is increasing with respect to $n$ you are essentially done.
Here $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number, $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$, and by Riemann sums
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(H_{2n}-H_n\right)=\lim_{n\to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k+n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\log 2.$$
As an alternative,
$$ H_{2n}-H_n = \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}$$
is clearly related with the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ at the origin.

Thus it is enough to prove $\log(2)<\frac{3}{4}$. We can do much better.
 By computing a polynomial remainder we have
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^4(1-x)^4}{1+x}\,dx =-\frac{621}{56}+16\log 2,$$
where the integrand function is positive but bounded by $\frac{1}{4^4}$ on $[0,1]$. It follows that:
$$ H_{2n}-H_n \leq \log(2) < \color{red}{\frac{39}{56}}.$$

Comment: "I solved it several years ago but can't recall my solution ... but can't recover the proper way to do it (without relying on integral calculus)."

Answer (score 0):

you can use this theorem, for the case a = 1, to prove the inequality.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Pre-Calculus Approach to Bounding by $\boldsymbol{\frac7{10}\lt\frac34}$**

Let
$$
a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}\tag1
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&=a_{n-1}+\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\tag2\\
&\le a_{n-1}+\frac1{4n-3}-\frac1{4n+1}\tag3\\
&\le\frac7{10}-\frac1{4n+1}\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac1{2n-1}+\frac1{2n}-\frac1n$
$(3)$: $\frac1{2n-1}-\frac1{2n}\lt\frac1{4n-3}-\frac1{4n+1}$
$(4)$: $(3)$ says that $a_n+\frac1{4n+1}$ is a decreasing sequence so $a_n+\frac1{4n+1}\le a_1+\frac15=\frac7{10}$

---

**Slight Improvement Using Subsequent Terms**

The argument above says that $a_n\le\frac7{10}$. However, $(2)$ says that $a_n$ is an increasing sequence and $(3)$ says that $a_n+\frac1{4n+1}$ is a decreasing sequence. This means that $a_n\le a_k+\frac1{4k+1}$ for any pair $n,k$.
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
k&a_k+\frac1{4k+1}&\text{approx}\\\hline
1&\frac7{10}&0.7\\
2&\frac{25}{36}&0.69444444\\
3&\frac{541}{780}&0.69358974\\
4&\frac{9901}{14280}&0.69334734\\
5&\frac{1747}{2520}&0.69325397\\
6&\frac{96079}{138600}&0.69321068\\
7&\frac{7244119}{10450440}&0.69318794\\
8&\frac{99917}{144144}&0.69317488\\
\end{array}
$$